# Translating "for the rest of the day"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What is the best way to translate the phrase "for the rest of the day" into Spanish, as in the following examples:

- I'm tired, I think I want to stay home for the rest of the day.
- Do you think it will keep raining for the rest of the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd translate it to:

> (por) el resto del día.

Your examples:

> Estoy cansado, creo que me quiero quedar en casa (por) el resto del día.
>
> ¿Piensas que seguirá lloviendo (por) el resto del día?

Comment: +1 Maybe "durante" can also be used instead of "por", though I'd say that just "el resto del día" is more usual.